thermal sum between two dates, from a daily data frame
I have a data frame with daily temperature data. I would like to calculate the sum in several columns, between two dates from a second data frame and create a output (results) in a new data frame.The thermal sum must be calculated in columns in data frame A, in dates interval that are in the lines of data frame B. Example: sum temperature between 02-15-2021 and 02-18-2021(in all A data frame columns), sum temperature between 02-18-2021 and 02-23-2021 (in all A data frame columns)...
#Daily temperature data frame
date <- as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-16-2021', '02-17-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-19-2021', '02-20-2021', '02-21-2021',
                  '02-22-2021','02-23-2021','02-24-2021','02-25-2021','02-26-2021',
                  '02-27-2021','02-28-2021','02-29-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y")
t0 <- c(26,27,28,30,32,27,28,29,27,26,28,29,28,25,26)
t0.5 <- t0-0.5
t1 <- t0-1
t1.5 <- t0-1.5
t2 <- t0-2
t5 <-t0-5
t8 <-t0-8
t8.5 <-t0-8.5
t10 <-t0-10
t20 <-t0-20
A <- data.frame(date, t0,t0.5,t1,t1.5,t2,t5,t8,t8.5,t10,t20)
head(A)

#Data frame with dates (sum between the #dates in the lines)
B <- data.frame(
  date2 = as.Date(c('02-15-2021', '02-18-2021', '02-23-2021',
                    '02-27-2021','02-28-2021'), "%m-%d-%Y"))
head(B)

B$from <- B$date2
B$to <- c(B$date2[-1], Inf)

nproc = ncol(A)
cont = 1

for (i in 2:ncol(A)) {
  print(i) 
  nome.var=colnames(A[i])
  variavela = nome.var[1]
  df2 = A[,c(1,i)]
  df2 = na.omit(df2)
  names(df2) = c("data","gd")
  
result=tapply(B, seq(nrow(B)), 
         function(x) {
           sum(df2[df2$data >= x$from & df2$data < x$to,]$gd)})
  

  cont = cont + 1
  
}
result


I was unable to save the results automatically.
The result I expect:


when you say from 2/15/21 to 2/18/21, I'd think that would include 2/18, so it'd be in col t0 26+27+28+30 = 111, not 81. Should the end date be only up to the dates preceding that date?

One way with dplyr (v1.1.0 or later (from Jan 2023) for join_by)
B |>
  left_join(A, join_by(from <= date, to > date)) |>
  summarize(across(-c(from:date), sum), .by = date2)

Result
       date2  t0  t0.5  t1  t1.5  t2  t5  t8  t8.5 t10 t20
1 2021-02-15  81  79.5  78  76.5  75  66  57  55.5  51  21
2 2021-02-18 146 143.5 141 138.5 136 121 106 103.5  96  46
3 2021-02-23 110 108.0 106 104.0 102  90  78  76.0  70  30
4 2021-02-27  28  27.5  27  26.5  26  23  20  19.5  18   8
5 2021-02-28  25  24.5  24  23.5  23  20  17  16.5  15   5

